# Q object (creating it with OR connection type at once)

Tags: python, django

Django 1.10.1

```
from django.db.models import Q
q = Q(title__icontains='r')

print(q)
>>> (AND: ('title__icontains', 'r'))
```

I've just thought whether it is possible to create the same but with OR logical operation.

I can obtain OR like this:

```
for item in q_objects:
    query |= item
```

Or somehow else (using lamdba).

But I don't feel this Q object. And this question may help me understand it better.

In other words whether it is possible to create via constructor an object  which will show (OR: ('title__icontains', 'r'))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hacky:

```
>>> Q.default = Q.OR
>>> q = Q(title__icontains='r')
>>> q
<Q: (OR: ('title__icontains', 'r'))>
```

Don't do this, because you have mutated the Q class for any future (and existing!) users.

More polite:

```
from django.db.models import Q

class MyQ(Q):
    default = Q.OR

q = MyQ(title__icontains='r')
```

But you now have an instance of a subclass of `Q`.  That shouldn't be a problem, really, but it's actual unnecessary for these simple objects.  Here's a more advanced way:

```
>>> from django.db.models import Q
>>> q = Q.__new__(Q)
>>> q.default = Q.OR
>>> q.__init__(title__icontains='r')
>>> q
<Q: (OR: ('title__icontains', 'r'))>
>>> Q.default  # existing Q instances are unaffected
u'AND'
```

Comment: Looks promising. I have to digest. Give me some time, please.

Comment: This works very well, like the avoidance of mutating the Q class.

Answer (score 1):

I recently found this and my working solution is:

```
filter_params = Q(
        **{key: value for key, value in filter_params_dict.items()},
        _connector=Q.OR,
    )

return Model.objects.filter(filter_params)
```

Answer (score 0):

@wim's answer is awesome!
Just a little addition:

Creating a new object for Q seem to be failing but you can make do with modifying the default connector with `Q.default = Q.OR`.

Additionally, you can pass all query parameters at once by doing:

```
 Model.objects.filter(Q(**query_dict))
 # Make sure to use query dictionary taking note of the fact that simply using
 # Double star operator would produce list values. You can do:
 dictionary = dict(query_dict)
 well_formed = {key: dictionary.get(key)[0] for key in dictionary.keys()}
 result = Model.objects.filter(Q(**query_dict))
```